# Why is Google Drive parents API present in v2 but not in v3?

Tags: google-drive-api

I need parent API to find file's parent info, but I can't see any API available in the v3 reference.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v3versusv2#v3_improvements), `Children` and `Parents` collections were removed in v3 because the functionality these collections provided can also be achieved using different methods, like `files.list`. The purpose behind these changes was removing duplicate capabilities.

So in v3, to get information on a parent's file, you can, for example:

- First, use [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get), indicating `parents` in the `fields` parameter. As a response, you will get a list of the id's of this file's parents.
- When you have successfully retrieved the parent id, you can get all information you want about it by using `Files.get` again using this id.